# How to save a string array to core data in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to save a string array to core data, but every time I try to read the array a get an empty one(I'm using NSString because of an answer I've read here, but it doesn't seem to work). Here is the code I use for saving :

```
let i = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Index")
     let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<PersonalTask> = PersonalTask.fetchRequest()
     do {
         let tasks = try PersistanceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
         self.personalTasks = tasks
     } catch {
         print("Error")
     }
     let pTask = personalTasks[i]
     var subtasks = pTask.subtasks
        print(subtasks as Any)
     let subtask = textView!.text as NSString
     subtasks?.append(subtask)
     print(subtasks)
     PersistanceService.saveContext()
```

Here is the function saveContext() :

```
static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

            let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Tasks")


        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("No descriptions found")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {

                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy



            return container
        }()

        // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    static func saveContext () {

            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {

                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
```

And here I am reading the data and getting an empty array :

```
let i = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Index")
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<PersonalTask> = PersonalTask.fetchRequest()
            do {
                let tasks = try PersistanceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                self.personalTasks = tasks
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            let pTask = personalTasks[i]
            print(pTask.title)
            print(pTask.notes)
            print(pTask.subtasks)
            subtasks = pTask.subtasks as [String]? ?? [NSString]() as [String]
            print(subtasks)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` What happens?

Comment: I get an empty array so nothing gets saved

Comment: @Dave can you show the core data model, please? I mean, the entity and his properties

Comment: the entity has the properties title and notes as Strings and Subtasks as transformable